# Cleaning Up Entire SVN Repository in URL

Tags: svn

I have an URL for a SVN repository (which can be accessed using an email and password for authentication purposes) and i'm trying to clean it up entirely (remove EVERY file and folder inside it) before i upload other projects of mine to it. I have Subversion installed but i can't find the appropriate command for this task. Some help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot answer to you with the detail. Because there is no information about your SVN client & O/S.

Anyway, the procedure is as the below.

1. svn delete all files
2. svn commit

That's all